# Unable to upload videos on Meta Business Suite

Tags: facebook, instagram

I just started using Meta Business Suite yesterday to schedule my Instagram Reel posts. When I first started using it everything worked fine. After I scheduled several posts it stopped working. Now when I go to upload a video it just gets stuck at 0%. I even tried uploading a video that I already uploaded and it still didn't work so I don't think it's a problem with the videos themselves. I'm using Chrome and have also tried using Safari and Firefox with no luck. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks.

Comment: Everybody, even if you do have the reputation to create an answer here: Please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Cole, please [edit] according to [ask] and especially make clear how you think that this is a programming related question.